# Enable VT-x in HP 8300 elite

Tags: virtualbox, vt-x

I have a HP 8300 elite (Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz). I'm trying to run a virtual machine via VirtualBox. But every time I start the VM, it says:

```
VT-x is disabled in the BIOS. (VERR_VMX_MSR_VMXON_DISABLED).
```

My lscpu output is like this:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 58
Stepping:              9
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              6784.74
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

I went into the BIOS but the things the can be tweaked is very limited and I couldn't find the VT-x setting.

Anybody know how to do this in this setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The setting in the BIOS isn't where you expect.

`Security > System Security > Virtualization Technology (VTx) [Enabled]`

Note that you should leave Virtualization Technology Directed I/O as it is, [Disabled] probably, as this isn't relevant.